# Why is my DataGrid not showing the values from my list?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

So I have 2 `DataGrid`s (because I haven't found a better way to do it the way I want it) and I have the following code in the .cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 23) });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1974, 1, 17) });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 3, Name = "Sammy Doe", Birthday = new DateTime(1991, 9, 2) });

    gridd.ItemsSource = users;

    string[] items = new string[]
    {
        "Asdf",
        "qwer",
        "sdfg",
        "wert",
    };
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

I only want to output this data in my `DataGrid` for testing purposes, but for some reason it doesn't work. Here is my xaml code:

```
<Grid>

    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="298.638" Margin="93.195,102.655,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="507.242">

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <!--Design kopfzeile-->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 0 0 0"/>
            </Style>

            <!--Deaktivieren Des rowheader-->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>

        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Artikelnummer" FontSize="10" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"  Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" FontSize="10" Header="Artikelnummer" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"  Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Matchcode" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"  Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Hersteller" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*"  Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="CheckBox" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <!--!!!!!!Haupt DataGrid !!!!!-->
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="282.293" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93.195,119,0,0" Name="gridd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="507.242" >
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="88.048">
                            <TextBox Name="IDSearcBox"  Width="88"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Name="NameSearchBox" Width="88"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Name="NameSearchBox" Width="88"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Name="NameSearchBox" Width="88"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Name="NameSearchBox" Width="88"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

It shows me the number of lines as I have saved in the list:

[image: Picture1]

But it does not show the values for it and especially since it is formatted in a weird way. I would be happy if someone sees my mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) but you do not supply data templates for displaying and editing.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Name="NameSearchBox" Width="88"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Alternatively, just use already built-in column types like [`DataGridTextColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0). In case you do not need custom data templates to display your data, there is no need for a template column.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding Id}">
   <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="88.048">
            <TextBox Name="IDSearcBox"  Width="88"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```